# Recursive zgrep not working

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, grep

I have a directory hierarchy that contains numerous `.gz` files.  I want to be able to recursively grep them for the string "foo".  From what I've read online the following should work:

```
zgrep -R -H "foo" .
```

However, this never returns any results.  If I replace the dot with the name of a file it does work.  For example,

```
zgrep -R -H "foo" myFile.gz
```

however, obviously, this no longer will be recursive.

I know "foo" is in some of the files because the following command returns many results:

```
find . -iname "*.gz" | xargs zgrep "output" | less
```

Does anyone know why my recursive zgrep command is not working.  I'm on a RHEL linux box

Answer (score 17):

The way I usually do is:

```
zgrep "foo" $(find . -name "*.gz")
```

or (however, the file name will be printed before each result instead of each line --**not just the files with matches**--):

```
find . -name "*.gz" -print -exec zgrep "foo" {} \;
```

If that command returns "Argument list too long", try this way:

```
for I in $(find . -name "*.gz"); do zgrep "foo" $I; done
```

Comment: `find . -name "*.gz"` for cross-platform compatibility on all POSIX systems

Comment: @kos: Added the dot for compatibility. Thank you.

Comment: `zgrep ... $(find ...)` breaks on filenames with spaces or other special characters. I recommend `find . -name "*.gz" -exec zgrep "foo" {} +`. This prints the filename on each matching line, unlike `find ... -exec ... {} \;` (another way to print the filename on each matching line is to use `zgrep -H`, if grep supports it).
See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187742/how-do-i-grep-recursively-through-gz-files

Answer (score 8):

You have to install zutils. This will replace the default and limited zgrep on your system with a recursive-able one.

On debian based systems you run `apt-get install zutils` then you can `zgrep -rH myword .` and use most of the other parameters from grep you know and love.

Comment: Hi down-voter. Would love to know why this is not a good idea. I personally used it and I thought it was great.

Comment: (+1) Not sure why the down vote. For those interested, there is a nice explanation about the zutils version vs the gzip version of zgrep here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187742/how-do-i-grep-recursively-through-gz-files

Answer (score 5):

Your almost there. Try this:

```
zgrep -R -H "foo" *.gz
```

EDIT: 
Hmmmm.... intriguing!

According to my zgrep, -R (Recursive) is not an option. Its simply not supported. Id have a check to see what the man page of your zgrep says.

One alternative, which depends on only one level of subdirectories is to do this:

```
zcat */*.gz | grep <needle>
```

But I would suggest that your find command is probably better!

Comment: When I try that I get: `zsh: no matches found: *.gz`

Answer (score 3):

I was also looking for the -R option, but this answer worked brilliantly for me:

`zgrep "foo" */*.gz`

That saved the day!

Answer (score 1):

it also works with:

zgrep "foo"   */ *.gz

Answer (score 0):

Use [sift](https://sift-tool.org/) - it's [super-fast](https://sift-tool.org/performance).

`sift -z foo`

`-z` is for unpacking gzips, it descends into subdirectories by default.
Shows filenames also by default (your `-H` option).

PS. Thanks to your question I discovered this tool today. Just battletested it, apart from the functionality you need, I have a 5x speedup on some production logs when comparing to `zgrep`.